# Hide category from navigation in bigcommerce

Tags: customization, categories, bigcommerce

I created a new category in my bigcommerce store. Now, I need to hide a this category from every page in the "main" site navigation, so that you cannot get to the page that displays the products in that category unless you are given the link.
Then I need hide all the "main" site navigation from that new product page so that you cannot go to the "main" site unless you go directly to it.
I know this is code customization, but unsure where to start. 
Can anyone guide me on where and what to do?
Thanks!

Comment: mmm, i did something similar,have you considered  use javascript to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to make this "hidden" category a subcategory of a parent that is hidden (from Products > Categories, click the green check to make it a red x).

Once this is done, it will be hidden from the menu navigation. From here, you would need to [create a custom template file](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Creating-Custom-Template-Files) and set this "hidden" subcategory page to use the custom template with the reduced navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Alyss's solution works, although it's worth giving a heads-up that when you try to unhide a subcategory — that's within a hidden parent category — BigCommerce will tell you that doing so will also unhide the parent category. You need to OK this, and on return to the category list re-hide the parent category alone. The subcategory will remain unhidden, and will function as described.